# Thread pool stuck on wait condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, mutex

I'm encountering a stuck in my c++ program using this thread pool class:

```
class ThreadPool {

    unsigned threadCount;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::list<std::function<void(void)> > queue;

    std::atomic_int jobs_left;
    std::atomic_bool bailout;
    std::atomic_bool finished;
    std::condition_variable job_available_var;
    std::condition_variable wait_var;
    std::mutex wait_mutex;
    std::mutex queue_mutex;
    std::mutex mtx;

    void Task() {
        while (!bailout) {
            next_job()();
            --jobs_left;
            wait_var.notify_one();
       }
    }

    std::function<void(void)> next_job() {
        std::function<void(void)> res;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> job_lock(queue_mutex);

        // Wait for a job if we don't have any.
        job_available_var.wait(job_lock, [this]()->bool { return queue.size() || bailout; });

        // Get job from the queue
        mtx.lock();
        if (!bailout) {
            res = queue.front();
            queue.pop_front();
        }else {
            // If we're bailing out, 'inject' a job into the queue to keep jobs_left accurate.
            res = [] {};
            ++jobs_left;
        }
        mtx.unlock();
        return res;
    }

public:
    ThreadPool(int c)
        : threadCount(c)
        , threads(threadCount)
        , jobs_left(0)
        , bailout(false)
        , finished(false)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
            threads[i] = std::move(std::thread([this, i] { this->Task(); }));
    }

    ~ThreadPool() {
        JoinAll();
    } 

    void AddJob(std::function<void(void)> job) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
        queue.emplace_back(job);
        ++jobs_left;
        job_available_var.notify_one();
    }

    void JoinAll(bool WaitForAll = true) {
        if (!finished) {
            if (WaitForAll) {
                WaitAll();
            }

            // note that we're done, and wake up any thread that's
            // waiting for a new job
            bailout = true;
            job_available_var.notify_all();

            for (auto& x : threads)
                if (x.joinable())
                    x.join();
            finished = true;
        }
    }

    void WaitAll() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(wait_mutex);
        if (jobs_left > 0) {
            wait_var.wait(lk, [this] { return this->jobs_left == 0; });
        }
        lk.unlock();
    }
};
```

gdb say (when stopping the blocked execution) that the stuck was in (std::unique_lock&, ThreadPool::WaitAll()::{lambda()#1})+58>

I'm using g++ v5.3.0 with support for c++14 (-std=c++1y)

How can I avoid this problem?

### Update

I've edited (rewrote) the class: https://github.com/edoz90/threadpool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h

Comment: I am fairly certain that operator-- on a std::atomic_bool is not an atomic operation. The only valid atomic operations are a bunch of atomic_foo() methods specified in the "Atomic operations library" section of the standard. As such, the mutex-less decrement+notify_one() is probably not getting properly sequenced with the mutex lock+wait(). I'm a bit of old-fashioned. I haven't gotten used all these new, fancy-shmancy atomic-this-es, and atomic-that-es. I use the old-school approach of mutex-protected variables, and notifies only while holding a mutex lock.

Comment: what is the purpose of `wait_mutex` ?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [all member functions of `atomic` are atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) and default memory order is `memory_order_seq_cst`

Comment: `operator--` on an atomic variable *is* atomic (equivalent to `fetch_add (-1)`). The problem here is that there is a race condition on `jobs_left` between the worker threads and the ones that calls `AddJob` and `JoinAll`. IMO you should get rid of that variable and work with the job queue directly, protecting it with the mutex, including inside `JoinAll`, and testing its size.

Comment: First you wait for `job_left`to be zero - then you raise `bailout` - then you add new jobs to the queue due to `bailout` - very complex - why do you do that? And what is the purpose of `finished` ? And don't you need to take `queue_mutex` in `JoinAll` ? Very complex code for a pretty simple class.

Comment: @4386427 wait_mutex is used to blocking the thread (the main in my case) calling `JoinAll` until all threads in pool are completed. `finished` and `bailout` are just in case the function `JoinAll` is called multiple times.
If you wish please add an answer with your paradigm :)

Comment: How would `JoinAll`be called multiple times? It is called from the  destructor! How would the destructor be called multiple times? Keep things simple... :-) I think you need to step back and reconsider your design - start by describing the exact purpose of each member variable/function. I'm sure you'll find a much more simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is a race condition on your job count. You're using one mutex to protect the queue, and another to protect the count, which is semantically equivalent to the queue size. Clearly the second mutex is redundant (and improperly used), as is the `job_count` variable itself.

Every method that deals with the queue has to gain exclusive access to it (even `JoinAll` to read its size), so you should use the same `queue_mutex` in the three bits of code that tamper with it (`JoinAll`, `AddJob` and `next_job`).

Btw, splitting the code at `next_job()` is pretty awkward IMO. You would avoid calling a dummy function if you handled the worker thread body in a single function.

EDIT:

As other comments have already stated, you would probably be better off getting your eyes off the code and reconsidering the problem globally for a while.

The only thing you need to protect here is the job queue, so you need only one mutex.

Then there is the problem of waking up the various actors, which requires a condition variable since C++ basically does not give you any other useable synchronization object.

Here again you don't need more than one variable. Terminating the thread pool is equivalent to dequeueing the jobs without executing them, which can be done any which way, be it in the worker threads themselves (skipping execution if the termination flag is set) or in the `JoinAll` function (clearing the queue after gaining exclusive access).

Last but not least, you might want to invalidate `AddJob` once someone decided to close the pool, or else you could get stuck in the destructor while someone keeps feeding in new jobs.

Comment: what do you mean with 'splitting the code at next_job() is pretty awkward'? :)

Comment: returning a function even when there is no code to execute is not necessary. You could rather execute the function only when an actual job has been dequeued.

Comment: sounds a lot cleaner and simpler. I don't really have time to test it, but it looks good. You still could implement the "no more jobs accepted" policy during termination. A simple assertion could do the trick. The idea is to make your class more robust by detecting weird use cases like someone keeping asking for jobs while someone else tries to close the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to keep it simple.
you seem to be using a mutex too many. So there's `queue_mutex` and you use that when you add and process jobs.

Now what's the need for another separate mutex when you are waiting on reading the queue?

Why can't you use just a conditional variable with the same `queue_mutex` to read the queue in your `WaitAll()` method?

### Update

I would also recommend using a `lock_guard` instead of the `unique_lock` in your `WaitAll`. There really isn't a need to lock the `queue_mutex` beyond the `WaitAll` under exceptional conditions. If you exit the `WaitAll` exceptionally it should be released regardless.

### Update2

Ignore my Update above. Since you are using a condition variable you can't use a lock guard in the `WaitAll`. But if you are using a `unique_lock` always go with the `try_to_lock` version especially if you have more than a couple control paths

Comment: Do you mean to just change the `wait_mutex` with the `queue_mutex`?

Comment: since its the same queue, the same mutex should be used to synchronize access to it.